# Tag rep requirement for Board Games beta is too high

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Board Games SE just went into private beta. Since it's new, there are no users with 150 rep, so no tags can be created. As such, no questions can be asked.

Is it possible to lower the threshold to 100 for a few days just to get things started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed.

[Meta.BoardGames post.](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/cannot-post-a-question-because-i-cannot-create-new-tags/8#8)

Comment: Thanx! The site is up and running.

Answer (score 4):

Betas are supposed to have much lower reputation requirements; it looks like something went wrong with this one. It was fixed in the last couple minutes; a bunch of the rep requirements dropped, including the one to create tags (it's at 1 now)